# AWS CodeBuild project with the same source multiple times

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

When trying to create a codebuild project with the same github repo used as the source I'm receiving an error from the CodeBuild API:

```
Invalid input: conflicting source locations 
(Service: AWSCodeBuild; Status Code: 400; 
Error Code: InvalidInputException; ...)
```

CDK code snippet:

```
    const project = new Project(this, 'PullRequestBuildProject', {
      source: Source.gitHub({
        owner: 'myorg',
        repo: 'myrepo',
        cloneDepth: 1,
        webhookFilters: [
          FilterGroup.inEventOf(
            EventAction.PULL_REQUEST_CREATED,
            EventAction.PULL_REQUEST_UPDATED,
            EventAction.PULL_REQUEST_REOPENED,
            EventAction.PUSH
          ).andBranchIsNot('main'),
        ],
      }),
      secondarySources: [
        Source.gitHub({
          identifier: MAIN_BRANCH_IDENTIFIER,
          owner: 'myorg',
          repo: 'myrepo',
          cloneDepth: 1,
          branchOrRef: 'main',
        }),
      ],
      ...
    });
```

Is it not possible to have a single build project which references different branches of the same repo?